# How can I add a vertical line to a line graph in excel?

Tags: excel, graph, line

[image: Example of what I have been able to do from other examples. Note: still not correct.]I have a list of years from 2019-2098 that I want to be the x-axis values. The y-axis will be from 0 to 1 for probabilities. The line graph will measure the survival probability curve in relation to years. The issue is that I need a vertical line to reside on the mark for year 2042. Is there a way to do this? Everything I have found online doesn't work! The photo is what I get from doing an online example. It produces a vertical line but not in the correct spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a separate data series that consists of (2042,0) and (2042,1).

Graph them as a scatterplot on top of your existing data. If needed, go to Change Chart Type and set the appearance to connect the two points with a line where the points don't show. Example: [Scatter plot without points showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMOD5.png)

Comment: I added a photo of what I get when I try that! It added a vertical line but not in the right spot

Comment: I adjusted the axis for the second series and now it lines up! Thanks a bunch!